# Login screen won't show up on external display after screen lock if lid is closed (xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, power-management

I have a DELL XPS 9570 laptop with xubuntu (18.04.1 LTS) installed.

My problem is that when I have the lid closed with external display connected, after I lock the screen I can't unlock it without opening a lid. So what I do now, every time I need to unlock the screen I open the lid, screen wakes up, I login and close the lid.

I'm also not fully sure if its a good thing or not but after I lock the screen, display goes black (but doesn't turn off, just like it would display black image). When I use mouse or keyboard, it wakes up and shows the greeter. Still of course only if lid is opened.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone ever would have this problem:

The issue was related to light-locker. I guess, for some reason system was getting suspended instead of locked, and to wake up from suspension, lid would need to be opened.

What I did, I removed light-locker, installed gnome-screensaver, rebooted and it worked.